# Подключение VK API

Tags: вконтакте, vkontakte-api

Подключаю API:

```
<script src="//vk.com/js/api/xd_connection.js?2" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

По `Http` работает, по `https` все нет, ошибки нет (`ssl` есть), из моей субд идет, из вк api не идет и не подключается `VK.api`, `VK.init - VK - undefined`

Comment: Кто не идёт, куда не идёт?

Comment: @klopp, Ну API не подгружается

Comment: И мы тут телепатически должны догадаться почему, предварительно расшифровав совершенно невнятное послание? Поставьте какой-нибудь firebug да посмотрите. Будут диагностика и подробности реализации - другой разговор.